# Excel to manipulate drop-down

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to manipulate a data validation drop-down in VBA code; I'm trying to create a macro that will run through each option on a list, save the sheet as a PDF, and proceed to the next option on the list until all are exhausted.

I have all the code figured out (I think) except for a command to move down the list; I've tried a few things with List-Index but can't quite get it to work. The sheet is "Cost Center Dashboard" and the cell with the validation list is **`"A2"`**

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your data validation drive from cells or a manually typed in list? You could convert it to a cell reference and loop through cells on a hidden setup tab.

Comment: It drives from cells on a "Lists" tab, but is itself dependent on another dropdown (that doesn't need to be automated). Basically, the user selects an EVP, and then the list for the Cost Center dropdown (the one we're trying to automate) populates based on the EVP that is selected. I think I see what you're getting at, though, I'll play around with it.

Comment: Yup, that works fine. Thank you so much for the suggestion, Wyatt!